# How to make "perfect" desktop cube?

Tags: compiz, cube

I was able to enable the Compiz Desktop Cube in Ubuntu 12.10.

I was wondering if it were possible, yet, to make a "perfect" cube. (Meaning instead of grey on the top and bottom, there were two more virtual desktops to replace them.)

Here is a picture of the grey area's I'm talking about:

[image: Grey desktop area's]

Is this possible?

Comment: The problem is, in ubuntu 12.10, doesnt exist the option for place pictures in the cube caps, only set the opacity, but doesnt works, only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to give yourself a fully working virtual desktop on the top and bottom of the cube.

The best option might be to just screenshot your desktop and place the png as the cube caps. That would give the illusion of the 'perfect' cube you are after.